# pdfMake javascript pdf content is misplaced

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfmake

I have the following code, i think is well written but it keeps rendering the pdf content misplaced,

> ```
> <html> <head>
> <title>Ingreso Simple</title>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/pdfmake.js"></script>
> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
> </head> <body> <script>
>
> var usuario = 'user';
> var left = 25;
> var right = 25;
> var top = 210;
> var bottom = 30;
>
>
> var dd = {
>     // a string or { width: number, height: number }
>     pageSize: 'LETTER',
>
>     // by default we use portrait, you can change it to landscape if you wish
>     pageOrientation: 'portrait',
>
>     // [left, top, right, bottom] or [horizontal, vertical] or just a number for equal margins
>     pageMargins: [left, top, right, bottom],
>     footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
>         return {
>             margin: [25,10,0,0],
>             text:currentPage.toString() + ' / ' + pageCount};
>     },
>     fontSize: 9,
>     header: {
>         margin: [0,25,25,25],
>         fontSize: 9,
>         stack: [
>             {columns: [
>                 {text: "LOGO", width: 150, margin:0},
>                 {stack: [
>                     {text: 'ENTERPRICE 1',fontSize: 14},
>                     {text: 'Adress 1',fontSize: 12},
>                     {text: '9999-999-99',fontSize: 12}
>                 ]},
>                 {stack: [
>                     {text: 'ASDDS',fontSize: 11},
>                     {text: '23/02/2016',fontSize: 11},
>                     {text: usuario, fontSize: 11}],
>                     alignment: 'right',
>                     width: 85
>                 }
>             ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25, 15, 0, 0],
>                 columns: ['ASDSDASDA', {text: 'SIMPLE', alignment: 'right'}]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25, 10, 0, 0],
>                 columns: [
>                     {   text: 'Fecha: 21/02/2016',
>                         width: 150
>                     },
>                     {   text: 'Carta de Porte:'},
>                     {   text: '4383',
>                         alignment: 'left',
>                         width: 100
>                     }]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,5,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Cliente:',bold:true}, 'ASDASDV.']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Deposito:',bold:true}, '995555']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Tipo :',bold:true}, 'CLASE 1']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Proce:',bold:true}, 'ASDASD']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Fecha y hora de entrada del vehiculo de transporte:',bold:true}]},
>                     '07/01/2016 14:52'
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Motorista:',bold:true}, 'CRISTIAN DANIEL VILLACORTA']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Licencia No.',bold:true}, '-07092207871017']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Cia. de Transporte:',bold:true}, 'PROPIO-MAQUINARIA AGRICOL']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Codigo de Transporte:',bold:true}, ' ']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Placa de vehiculo:',bold:true}, '103797']},
>                     {text:[{text:'No. Marchamo:',bold:true}, 'MARC1']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Fecha de descarga:',bold:true}, '07/01/2016']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Hora inicio:',bold:true}, '15:14'], width:85},
>                     {text:[{text:'Hora fin:',bold:true}, '00:00'], width:85},
>                     {text:[{text:'Ubicacion:',bold:true}, 'BODEGA 1']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Muelle:',bold:true}, 'MUELLE 1']}
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 margin: [25,0,0,0],
>                 columns:[
>                     {text:[{text:'Descargado por: ',bold:true}, 'Cliente']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Mercaderia Paletizada? ',bold:true}, 'Granel']},
>                     {text:[{text:'Utiliza DAN? ',bold:true}, 'SI']}
>                 ]
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>     content: [
>         {
>             fontSize: 9,
>             table:{
>                 headerRows:1,
>                 widths: [ 60, 60, 145, 135, 55, 55 ],
>                 body:[
>                     [
>                         'Codigo Mercaderia',
>                         'Codigo Referencia',
>                         'Descripcion Mercaderia',
>                         {stack:['Cantidad de bultos', {columns:['Declarada', 'Recibida', 'Diferencia']}],alignment:
> 'center'},
>                         'Unidad Medida',
>                         'Estado Mercaderia'
>                     ],[
>                         '07951',
>                         ' ',
>                         'Equipo hidraulico industrial',
>                         {stack:[{columns:['100','101','-1']}]},
>                         'BTOS',
>                         'Bueno'
>                     ],[
>                         '07951',
>                         ' ',
>                         'Equipo hidraulico industrial',
>                         {stack:[{columns:['100','101','-1']}]},
>                         'BTOS',
>                         'Bueno'
>                     ],[
>                         '10094461 1',
>                         ' ',
>                         'Exhividores de piso',
>                         {stack:[{columns:['150','150','0']}]},
>                         'BTOS',
>                         'Bueno'
>                     ],
>                     [' ',' ', ' ', {stack:[{columns:['5400','5404','-4']}]}, ' ',' ']]
>             }
>         },
>         {margin:[0,10,0,0], text:[{text:'Observaciones: ', bold:true}, 'ASDASDASDAS']}
>     ]
> };
> var asdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);
> asdf.open(); </script> </body> </html>
> ```

The code should create a pdf with a header and a table but it prints this way:
[image: screenshot of the generated pdf]

I marked in red the misplaced text (it should be a table), I don´t know why it keeps putting it in that place.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that variables left, right, top and bottom conflicts with some other variables in the scope, so the answer is rename variables and replace where they are used:

```
var _left = 25;
var _right = 25;
var _top = 210;
var _bottom = 30;

// [...] (inside dd object)
pageMargins: [left, top, right, bottom],
```

After this replacement the pdf was perfectly rendered